# BootstrapValidator & Ace Editor: manually updating validation status

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, ace-editor

I use JQuery and BootstrapValidator 0.5.2 for form validation (at the moment I stuck with the older version).
I want to validate an Ace editor field (http://ace.c9.io), it must not be empty.
Validation works fine, the problem is that I cannot update the fields validation status manually.
Anyone knows how can I access the bootstrap validation functions of an Ace editor field?
Basically my code is as follows:

```
<div id="text" name="text" class="ace-editor" data-bv-field="text"></div>

$('#form').formValidation({
    fields: {
        'text': {
            validators: {
            callback: {
                // check content of ace editor
                message: 'Mandatory',
                callback: function(value, validator) {
                    var editor = ace.edit('text'),
                        ok = (editor.session.getValue() != ''),
                        status = (ok) ? 'VALID' : 'INVALID';

                    // gives error: $(...).data(...) is undefined
                    //$('#text').data('bootstrapValidator').updateStatus('text', status, null);

                    // gives error TypeError: this.options.fields[b] is undefined in bootstrapValidator.min.js
                    $('#text').bootstrapValidator().data('bootstrapValidator').updateStatus('text', status, null);

                    return ok;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$('#text').data('bootstrapValidator').updateStatus('text', status, null);
```

should be:

```
$('#form').data('bootstrapValidator').updateStatus('text', status, null);
```

the first parameter is supposed to be the form, not the element you are updating.  Hope this helps.